# Failed to get an object property that containing ":protected"

Tags: php, object, joomla

I used the code below to get the object's property `_items:protected`, but no luck.

```
$obj = JSite::getMenu();
print_r($obj->_items:protected);
```

Object output

```
JMenuSite Object
(
    [_items:protected] => Array
        (
            [101] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 101
                    [menutype] => mainmenu
```

Anyone know what wrong with my code? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to access a protected property from outside the class.
A protected property can only be accessed from within the class itself or classes that inherit from that class.

Read up on OOP access modifiers.